# C# Multiple null checks vs branched single null checks

Tags: c#

I was reading the framework code (dotnet471rs3) and came across this block of code in Path (System.IO)

```
public static String Combine(String path1, String path2, String path3, String path4) {
        if (path1 == null || path2 == null || path3 == null || path4 == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException((path1 == null) ? "path1" : (path2 == null) ? "path2" : (path3 == null) ? "path3" : "path4");
```

Wouldn't it be better to do this like

```
if (path1 == null)
   throw new ArgumentNullException("path1");
else if (path2 == null)
   throw new ArgumentNullException("path2");
```

Ignoring the nameof use here or lack of, but my question is why one is done over the other ? Or is it because it potentially has no difference to performance etc ? Is there something simple that i overlooked ?

Comment: _"Wouldn't it be better to do this like"_ - What is your definition of "better"?

Comment: I think the two would be the same, since C# is using lazy evaluation (if first or condition satisfies, no need to evaluate the rest). The difference is that you read/write them in 1 line or more lines.

Comment: I would say the performance difference is likely so minimal as to be of no concern. Therefore (personally) I would favour the readability/maintainability of what you propose (second code snippet).

Comment: "Better" in the sense of not checking twice. I am not an expert at this, but it seemed odd that framework code does what looks like duplicate checks.

Comment: @SenthilRamanathan: `"Better" in the sense of not checking twice` I just want to remark here that _performance at all costs_ is not a good approach. The difference in performance here is negligible, but the difference in readability less so. Sacrificing everything else for the sake of performance can cause big issues down the line. Priorities are not absolutes. That being said, it's still useful to have a discussion about if the work is effectively done twice, regardless of how minute the performance difference is. This comment is a tangent, not a rebuttal.

Comment: @Flater Agreed. Performance is the not the best description in my question for what i was trying to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Performance

They're *mostly* equivalent. There is a minute difference between them, but it's so small that it can be ignored for all practical purposes.

For example, let's see what happens if `path1` is null:

*The original*

- `||` would immediately resolve to true so the other null checks are no longer evaluated ([explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-or-operator)).
- **However**, the original would then perform the same null check again on the `throw` line.

*Your version*

- It would not have any other operands to check anyway, so it obviously only performs one null check just like the original.
- It does not need to perform the same null check on the `throw` line, since it knows `path1` is null (as opposed to the original, which only knows that *one of the paths* is null, but it has forgotten which one).

Since you're throwing an exception and exiting the method, the subsequent `if` blocks are ignored. **This would be different** if you didn't throw an exception and instead logged a message and then continued with the method.

- The original version would not check the remaining `path` variables for null. It would only ever log the **first** null value encountered.
- Your version would still perform all the other checks, and would log a message for **every** null value found.

---

### Readability

I like your version a lot more. It's much clearer. It also opens the door to method abstraction; you could e.g. rewrite this as:

```
ThrowIfNull(path1);
ThrowIfNull(path2);
ThrowIfNull(path3);
ThrowIfNull(path4);
```

(The implementation of `ThrowIfNull` seems simple enough that I've omitted it)

---

### Summary

- The performance difference can swing either way, based on whether the `if` body exits the method (in which case you're faster) or doesn't (in which case the original is faster because it doesn't check for a second null)
- Your version is more readable than the original.
- The performance cost from doing a few extra null checks does not outweigh the readability argument here; in my opinion. I would go with your version for readability's sake.